# Difference between using and using = for types?

Tags: c++, using

Consider the following two `using` statements:

```
using ::space1::space2::MyType;
using MyType = ::space1::space2::MyType;
```

It seems that after the `using`, both ways allows us the use `MyType` directly (without any qualifiers).

So what's the difference between the above two?

Comment: Well, as an example, the second expression can be used to define aliases like `using Foo = Bar<MyClass>` as well, while the first one cannot. Anyway, in the first example you are exporting an existing name, in the second one you are creating a new alias.

Comment: The first one is a [using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) while the second is a [namespace alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias).

Comment: @crayzeewulf as the title of the question mentions types, I'd say that the second is a [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) rather than a ns alias.

Comment: Yeah, he modified the question, was without `MyType` the first time. :-) ... See the other comments.

Comment: @Christophe You are correct. The second is a [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias). I was hasty and did not notice the missing `namespace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, in the first case you are actually exporting a name from a namespace to the one which contains the `using` declaration, while in the second case you are defining an alias in the namespace that contains the `using` statement that points to that specific name and its surrounding namespace.

As an example, with the second expression you can define aliases like the following one:

```
using Foo = Bar<MyClass>;

template <class C>
using Foo = Bar<C, MyClass>;
```

While the first `using` expression cannot, it serves merely to let names to be available in different spaces than the ones that contain them.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using) for further details regarding using directives, using declarations and aliases (type and template ones).

Answer (score 1):

The first one lets you refer to the variable/type by its *unqualified* name.

The second one declares a **new** type name in the enclosing namespace.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [skypjack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4987285/skypjack)'s nice answer, for the records, there's another difference when the statemetns are used inside a class definition.

Inside a class definition, the using declaration shall introduce a member of the base class, whereas, the type alias is still a type alias:

```
namespace space1 {  namespace space2 {  class MyType {}; } }

struct s1  {
    using ::space1::space2::MyType;  // error 
    MyType b; 
};
struct s2 {
    using MyType = ::space1::space2::MyType;  // perfectly valid
    MyType a; 
};
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I've not considered them also as enclosed in a class definition in my response, my fault. Thank you.